# Unable to fetch data from webservice with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to load some very simple data in JSON format, generated by a webservice, using `Retrofit` and `Gson` and also trying to implement `MVVM` architecture, but I'm getting a `null` value when calling data from  `ViewModel`:
I've seen many SO questions (or maybe not so many) but can't figure out where and why I'm getting this problems.

So, what I have is this

**JSON RESPONSE**: This could be either this one:

```
{
    "ok": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "test1",
            "pass": "123",
            "reg_date": "2020-05-20 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

or this:

```
{
    "error": [
        {
            "message":"user doesn't exists"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've created the correspondign POJOs for each response type, which I'll omit for simplicity. But also I've created a generic POJO for handling the response (thanks to @Công Hải, )

**POJOGenericResponse.java*

```
public class POJOGenericResponse{
    @SerializedName("ok")
    private LiveData<ArrayList<POJOUsr>> user;
    @SerializedName("error")
    private LiveData<ArrayList<POJOError>> error;

    //Constructor and Getters...
}
```

**JsonApi.java**

```
public interface JsonApi {
    @GET("SelectAllUsr.php")
    Call<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> getGenericResponse();
}
```

I don't know how this class should be called, according to its purpose and name conventions

**RetrofitInstance.java**

```
public class RetrofitInstance {
    private static String URL_BASE = "http://192.168.0.35/app_android/webservices/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static Gson gson;

    public Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL_BASE)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**LoginRepository.java**

```
public class LoginRepository{
    private RetrofitInstance retrofitInstance;
    private JsonApi jsonApi;
    private LiveData<POJOGenericResponse> genericResponse;
    private Call<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> call;

    public LoginRepository() {
        retrofitInstance = new RetrofitInstance();
        jsonApi = retrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(JsonApi.class);
        call = jsonApi.getRespuestaGenerica();
    }

    //TODO: This should be done in another class??
    public LiveData<POJOGenericResponse> getGenericResponse() {
        call.clone().enqueue(new Callback<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> call, Response<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    genericResponse= response.body();
                } else {
                    //
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                //
            }
        });
        return genericResponse;
    }
}
```

**LoginViewModel.java**

```
public class LoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private RepositorioLogin loginRepository;
    private MutableLiveData<POJOGenericResponse> serverResponse;

    public ViewModelLogin(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        loginRepository = new RepositorioLogin();
        serverResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public void setServerResponse(){
        serverResponse.setValue(loginRepository.getGenericResponse().getValue());
    }

    public LiveData<POJORespuestaGenerica> getServerResponse(){
        return serverResponse;
    }
}
```

Here's where the data should be shown

**FragmentData.java**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);
        TextView exampleText = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_test);

        LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        loginViewModel.getServerResponse().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<POJORespuestaGenerica>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(POJOGenericResponse pojoGenericResponse) {
                if (pojoGenericResponse.getUser() != null) {
                    exampleText.setText(pojoGenericResponse.getUser().getValue().get(0).getUsername());
                }
                if (pojoGenericResponse.getError() != null) {
                    exampleText.setText(pojoGenericResponse.getError().getValue().get(0).getMensaje());
                }
            }
        });
```

When debugging, the error that I get is

> response = Cannot find local variable 'response'         serverResponse.setValue(loginRepository.getGenericResponse().getValue());\n = java.lang.NullPointerException
>   response = Cannot find local variable 'response'

which describe the problem by itself, but can't manage to solve it.

Also, any recommendation on the implementation of the `MVVM` architecture will be very appreciated.

Beforehand, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an incorrect bit --

```
public LiveData<POJOGenericResponse> getGenericResponse() {
        call.clone().enqueue(new Callback<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> call, Response<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    genericResponse= response.body();
                } else {
                    //
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LiveData<POJOGenericResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                //
            }
        });
        return genericResponse;
    }
```

So `onResponse` is an asynchronous call and you are returning the `return genericResponse;` immediately from the method.

Rather than getting a return from this method change it to void and directly observe on `private LiveData<POJOGenericResponse> genericResponse;`

Comment: that clarifies a lot. Thanks!! I'm working on the second part of your answer right now, it's not very clear for me, I'm very noob on this xD

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore, but don't show any data.
Where should I observe the ```genericResponse```, in the same ```ViewModel```, ```Repository``` or in the fragment? 
I think I'm missing some steps.

Comment: You should observe it in your fragment/activity whichever you are using.